# How do I process output from the command line into python?

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook

So I found this tool: https://github.com/elceef/dnstwist and I want to pass a list of domains into that tool then take the output and visualize it.
It operates through the command line, but how do I automate entering each domain and process the output automatically as well?
By the way I am using colab, so I would need a solution using jupyter notebooks!

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to run a program from Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do I pass the output back into python, especially with that banner?

Comment: The library is written in Python; probably simply `import` it and call its functions, instead of detouring via the shell.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` allows you to read the output of the command.

Comment: Though for simple things you should always prefer `subprocess.run()` or one of the legacy convenience functions like `subprocess.check_output()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically I would not use the provided *cli* – although this would also be possible.

Instead you can create a small python script to do this.
Import `dwintwist` in your script and have a look at the `main` function in `dwintwist.py` to see how you call this.

Doesn't look to hard, but I don't know your programming skill level of course.